# Sometimes a python thread is not called and exited

Tags: python, multithreading

```
    def thread_run(self):
        print ('start')
 
        run()
 
        print ('before')
        threading.Timer(2, self.thread_run).start()
        print ('after')

        return True
```

The thread_run is like the above so that it is called every 2 seconds.

But sometimes it is not called.
i.e. sometimes 'start' was not printed and the program exited even after both of 'before' and 'after' were printed.

Which case does it occur in?

Because the thread is repeated infinitely, I sometimes terminate the program with ctrl + c by force. And then I re-excute the program.
Is it caused by this?

Comment: Can  you explain why you think you need to understand what happens when you create an infinite number of threads, rather than how to write code that only spawns as many threads as you actually _need_?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - Its not obvious why creating a thread in a thread causes a problem. You don't need to do your own `.join` with a `Timer` thread. Its a question of python's exit processing which may not be common knowledge. Its not documented in the `Timer` docs itself.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why "start" is not printed. If there was code before `print("start")` and it raised an exception, that would explain it. Or if the program exited without the normal python exit processing (calling `os.exit` for instance) that would too.

Python keeps a list of threads and waits for them to complete when exiting. A `Timer` does its own `join` which removes the timer thread from that list, so usually you don't have to do anything special with them.

But it's a problem at program exit. If a timer hasn't fired yet, your program will wait until the timer thread runs and exits. So, "start" should be printed, even on program exit. But your timer creates a new timer, putting another thread on the exit list, and Python will keep waiting. That's why you need Ctrl-C.

One solution is to mark the thread as a "daemon" so that it is not put on the wait list.

```
def thread_run(self):
    print ('start')

    run()

    print ('before')
    t = threading.Timer(2, self.thread_run)
    t. daemon = True
    t.start()
    print ('after')

    return True
```